# Will adding a second sink in a bathroom with only one sink currently reduce the water pressure?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink

We have two bathrooms that have plenty of space to each add a second sink on the vanity. So essentially:

- Master Bathroom currently has 1 sink, we want to turn it into a Jack&Jill
- Guest Bathroom currently has 1 sink, we want to turn it into a Jack&Jill

I looked up all the connections necessary, so the install isn't an issue. But: Would that essentially reduce the water pressure in each sink to half of that of before?

Comment: I think there are quite a few variables - the main supply line size, water pressure, the distance of the new sink to the main supply line, will all sinks in use simultaneously....

Comment: Mostly "when both in use" and also the size of the pipe to it matters (but most modern sink faucets are fairly low flow to meet modern water standards, and have tiny internal piping, so likely not anything like "half pressure" when both in use unless the pipe to it is very small or partially blocked.)

Answer (score 3):

The pressure may be slightly reduced while in use. Most homes have at least 1/2” plumbing and the sink cartridges usually have ~1/8” orifices in the faucet on each side so if you turn all 4 on at the same time you probably will notice a difference but not a significant one. Now a tub faucet that would be a different answer.